# about Machine Learning：Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
# Extract the features for a given application
features = extract_features(file_path)
# Form the feature vector
feature_vector = create_vector_single(features)
# Load the pre configured feature model from a pickle file
model = pickle.load(open("feature_model.p", "rb"))
# Reduce the feature vector into size 12
feature_vector_new = model.transform(feature_vector)

# Load the pre-trained model from a pickle file
clf = pickle.load( open( "kfold_train_data.p", "rb" ) )

# Perform prediction using the model
result = clf.predict(feature_vector_new)
```

An error occur on `feature_vector_new = model.transform(feature_vector)`

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

then i solve it with :

```
# Reduce the feature vector into size 12
vec = [feature_vector]
vec = np.array(vec).reshape(1, -1)
feature_vector_new = model.transform(vec)
```

it generates another error:

```
AttributeError: 'SelectFromModel' object has no attribute 'norm_order'
```

Comment: can you be clear about the functions you used. Are these belong to any standard library functions or is it your own functions.

Comment: i only clear the approximate function，in this，the function of this function is probably is the normalized feature variable.And these belong to `scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

When I tracked similar code, I found that there was one less parameter `norm_order` in the generated model object--`feature_model.p`.

Answer：regenerate one model,then this question was solved!

```

```
file_name = sys.argv[1]
op_file = open('final_data.csv','w+')
ffile = open('final_selected_features.txt','w+')
header = ""
dataX = []
dataY = []
feature_names = []
with open(file_name,'r') as fp:
    for i,line in enumerate(fp):
        if i == 0:
            header = line
            feature_names = [x for x in line.strip().split(',')[:-1]]
        else:
            dd = [int(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')]
            dataX.append(dd[:-1])
            dataY.append(dd[-1])


lsvc = LinearSVC(C=0.01, penalty="l1", dual=False).fit(dataX, dataY)
with open('feature_scores.txt','w+') as aa:
    for a in sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x,4), lsvc.coef_[0]),feature_names), reverse=True):
        aa.write(a[1]+'\t'+str(a[0]) + '\n')

model = SelectFromModel(lsvc, prefit=True)
pickle.dump( model, open( "feature_model.p", "wb" ) )
dataX_new = model.transform(dataX)
```

```